# how to extract year from date with timestamp from jcr:property of a page using querybuilder api aem

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have two filters on page viz. Year & Category. Based on this filters i need to retrieve the pages from the repository and show it on the page. I am using querbuilder api to fetch the pages based on searching "year & category" properties in the page property of the list of pages.However, I have a date property in page properties of list of pages from where i need to compare the year filter of my query. But filter=year is in the format "2017" & date=timestamp in pageproperties of page is in format of "2017-09-18T01:15:00.000+05:30". So how do i compare the year filter & date in page properties to fetch these particular pages through my query.

Code Snippet

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(year)) {
    map.put("3_property", "year");
    map.put("3_property.value", 2017);
}
```

Property
[image]

Comment: Is `DateFormat.Parse(...).getCalendar().get(YEAR)` not helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DateRangePredicateEvaluator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/DateRangePredicateEvaluator.html) to achieve the desired result. You can do a simple String concatenation to set the upper and lower bounds for the predicate evaluator.

So in your case, the query would be.

```
map.put("daterange.property", "date"); //Since the property name is date as per your image.
map.put("daterange.lowerBound", year + "-01-01"); //First day of the year
map.put("daterange.upperBound", year + "-12-31"); //Last day of the year
```

and that should get you the required results.

Comment: Hi Rakhi, but the property coming from my page filter is year (e.g. 2014) on which i am creating my query and page property of page which it would compare is in "2014-09-18T01:15:00.000+05:30" format. So i need to extract year from it first and then compare it with my query param while executing the query.

Comment: Yes, the query that I gave would list all nodes which have their dates in the year 2014. You do not need to manually extract the value and then compare.